# Mixed properties in 'source' column/fields in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure Data Factory to copy data from a source folder (Azure Blob) that has multiple folders inside it (and each one of those folders has a year as it's name, and inside the folders are the Excel spreadsheets with the data) to a SQL Server table. I want to iterate through the folders, select the folder name, and insert the name into a column in a table, so for each data read inside the files in the folder, the folder name where this data is will be in the table, like this:

```
Data 1   |Data 2   |Year
------------------------
A        |abc      |2020
B        |def      |2020
C        |ghi      |2021
D        |jkl      |2022
E        |lmn      |2023
```

My pipeline is like this:
[image: 1]

I have a Get Metadata activity called Get Metadata1 [image: 2] pointing to the folders, and after that a ForEach to iterate through the folders [image: 3] with two activities: one "Set variable" activity setting a variable named FolderYear [image: 4] with @item().name as value (to select the folder name) and a Copy activity which creates a additional column [image: 5] into the dataset named Year using the variable.

I'm trying to map the additional Year column to a column in the table, but when I debug the pipeline, the following error appears:

```
{ "errorCode": "2200", "message": "Mixed properties are used to reference 'source' columns/fields in copy activity mapping. Please only choose one of the three properties 'name', 'path' and 'ordinal'. The problematic mapping setting is 'name': 'Year', 'path': '','ordinal': ''. ", "failureType": "UserError", "target": "Copy data1", "details": [] }
```

It's possible to insert the folder name which I'm currently iterating into a database column?

Comment: There is no need to use "Set variable" activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a same test and copied the data(include the folder name) into a SQL table successfully.
I have two folders in the container and each folder contains one cvs file for test.
[image]

The previous settings are the same as you.
Inside the **ForEach** activity, I use the **Additional columns** to add the folder name to the datasource.

[image]

After copied into a SQL table, the results show as follow:
[image]

---

**Update:**
My file structure is as follows:
[image]
You can use expression `@concat('FolderA/FolderB/',item().name)`:
[image]

Comment: Okay, I tried to do like you did, but in my case, the dataset with the files is inside another folder, like this: FolderA/FolderB/[insert year here]/[insert files here]. You referenced the folder using @item().name as a wildcard path. Is there a way to insert a regular expression that references the folder inside a folder?

Comment: Yes, please see my update part of the answer and correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: I solved the problem. The files that I'm trying to work with have the year in their names, so I moved them all together in one folder then used the split() function to get the year from their names. Thanks for the help!